# how to build the Gson for creating different pojo classes based on the json string's data using gson.fromJson()

Tags: gson, runtimetypeadapterfactory

When using retrofit to get json from remote and parsing to into pojo,
and the json has "type" in each item, based on the type different pojo classes will be created.

```
{
"result": [
    {
        "type": "stroy",
        "stroy_data_1": xxx,
        "story_data_2": yyy
    },
    {
        "type": "detail",
        "detail_data_1": 111,
        "detail_data_2": 222
    }
]
}
```

with retofit, it could be done by `addConverterFactory` with a `Converter.Factory`, like:
here with `RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory` it builds a `dataAdapter` to create the Gson and ask to create calsses based on the "type"

```
fun createCustomeDataGson(): Gson {
    val dataAdapter = RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory
            .of(TopLevelItem::class.java, "type")
            .registerSubtype(Story::class.java, "story")
            .registerSubtype(Detail::class.java, "detail")

    return GsonBuilder()
            .registerTypeAdapterFactory(dataAdapter)
            .create()
}
```

with the Gson a Converter.Factory is created for retrofit to `addConverterFactory`

```
fun getGsonConverterFactory(): Converter.Factory {
    return GsonConverterFactory.create(createCustomeDataGson())
}

fun <T> createRetrofitService(clazz: Class<T>,
                              baseUrl: String,
                              okHttpClient: OkHttpClient): T {
    val restAdapter = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(baseUrl)
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .addConverterFactory(getGsonConverterFactory())
            .build()
    return restAdapter.create(clazz)
}
```

finally the retrofit service is cretaed:

```
fun createCustomeDataApiApi(): CustomeDataApi {
    val baseUrl = getBaseUrl(defaultBaseUrl)
    return createRetrofitService(CustomeDataApi::class.java, baseUrl, okHttpClient)
}

internal interface CustomeDataApi {
    @GET("/api/customedata")
    fun getCustomData(@QueryMap params: Map<String, String>?): Call<DataResponse>
}
```

It works  in this way.
But there are use cases not using the retorfit
        and only having a json string, and would like to use `gson.fromJson<T>(jsonString, dataClassType)`,
how to configure the gson  for generating the class by the "type" in the json?

Answer (score 0):

find a sample [here](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/how-to-deserialize-a-list-of-polymorphic-objects-with-gson)

```
String responseJson = new String(responseBody); // from the service endpoint

// which format has the response of the server
final TypeToken<ServiceResponse> requestListTypeToken = new 
TypeToken<ServiceResponse>() {};

// adding all different container classes with their flag
final RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory<AbstractContainer> typeFactory = 
RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory  
    .of(Animal.class, "type") // Here you specify which is the parent class and what field particularizes the child class.
    .registerSubtype(Dog.class, "dog") // if the flag equals the class name, you can skip the second parameter. This is only necessary, when the "type" field does not equal the class name.
    .registerSubtype(Cat.class, "cat");

// add the polymorphic specialization
final Gson gson = new 
GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapterFactory(typeFactory).create();

// do the mapping
final ServiceResponse deserializedRequestList = gson.fromJson(responseJson, requestListTypeToken.getType() );
```

not sure why it needs  `gson.fromJson(responseJson, requestListTypeToken.getType() );` though,  could it be done by

```
gson.fromJson(responseJson, ServiceResponse.class);
```

? what is the difference?

some ref: [1;](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/extras/src/main/java/com/google/gson/typeadapters/RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory.java)  [2;](https://www.novatec-gmbh.de/en/blog/gson-object-hierarchies/)  [3;](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=com.google.gson.GsonBuilder)